.net aspire create migration issue: wrong connectionstring
I am trying to add an initial migration in my aspire project.
I am using Aspire.Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql
Below is my code for microservice and apphost.
AppHost
var builder = DistributedApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

//var mysqlPassword = builder.AddParameter("sql-password", secret: true);

var mysqlDbContainer = builder.AddMySql("mysql-db-container").WithDataVolume();
var identityDbCatalog = mysqlDbContainer.AddDatabase("identitydb");

builder.AddProject<Projects.SchoolFee_IdentityService>("identityservice").WithReference(identityDbCatalog);

builder.Build().Run();

MicroService
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.AddMySqlDbContext<IdentityServiceDbContext>("identitydb");
builder.AddServiceDefaults();
...

When I run dotnet ef migrations add Initial in my microservice, I get below error
Execution attempt. Source: 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.AspireEFMySqlExtensions.ServerVersion/(null)/Retry', Operation Key: '', Result: 'Access denied for user ''@'172.17.0.1' (using password: NO)', Handled: 'False', Attempt: '0', Execution Time: 209.9911ms
      MySqlConnector.MySqlException (0x80004005): Access denied for user ''@'172.17.0.1' (using password: NO)

However, connectionstring is working fine if i try to debug.
How can I create migrations so that it can be applied during deployments?

Check Apply Entity Framework Core migrations in .NET Aspire. Notice that the DbContext and its migrations live in a separate Data project and are used by Aspire, they don't depend on Aspire. If you think about it, that makes perfect sense. With Aspire, you need to start the host to retrieve the settings used by EF Core.

@PanagiotisKanavos it does not cover the add migration part.

It does, in the Create Migrations section: dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate ..... It's not a migrations guide so it doesn't show how to add more migrations, just the first one.

@PanagiotisKanavos exactly what my query is about. dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate does not work in my test case.

You didn't post any code about a MicroService.Data project that holds the DbContext. Nor did you post the complete command line you used to apply the migration. The error  Access denied for user ''@'172.17.0.1' (using password: NO) suggests no credentials were used. MySQL doesn't support Windows authentication so you have to specify connection credentials in dotnet ef .....
